# Uninstall web essentials

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-essentials

I have downloaded a .vslx file and installed which cuases web essentials to be part of VS 2012.

This may be a silly question.
But How can I remove the webessentials from vs.I cannot find such an option in VS 2012. I found it total messy

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.
From extensions and updates in tools we can remove the plugins of VS